# Setting a feed limit on the Eventbrite API

Tags: api, feed, eventbrite

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a limit as to how many events show in my feed. I can't seem to find any documentation as to how to do this. I only wish to show 3 events on my website's homepage, but it automatically lists them all.

I don't see anything under the request parameters (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_new/) but I'm wondering if there is more documentation elsewhere.

Comment: What API call are you using?  Which feed are you talking about exactly?

Comment: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_new/ - This is the API I am using. I just don't see anything that allows for you to set a number of posts.

Answer (score 0):

event_new creates new events...it does not *list* events.  So, you can't be using this API to create a "feed".

To list events, there are two API endpoints...[user_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/) and [organizer_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/).  user_list_events has more controls over the return data, so you should use that one.

Since there are not pagination controls on either of those methods, you will need to filter the result set yourself in whatever client library you are using.